# How to match color in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have an image that I would like to sample its background color. However the problem is that the color is not consistent throughout the image and gives a slightly patterned appearance. I would like to know if I could create a swatch and use this (randomized?) texture to effectively " blend" the image and background.

I vaguely remember doing something in Photoshop to remedy this but don't know how to go about it in Illustrator.

I have attached an image [image].

As you can see the I have used the eye dropper tool to match the color(on the top), but that only gives me a single color from one pixel.

Thanks!

Comment: Kind of odd.. ask about Illustrator but accept a Photoshop answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are referring to [Content-Aware](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/using/content-aware-fill.html) filling, which basically works like the spot healer brush - on a much larger scale.

Content aware usage:

[image] [Source](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/using/content-aware-fill.html)

(The eyedropper is for selecting a single pixel color, it did exactly what it should.)

**No, Illustrator does not have that capability,**

It needs to be able to accurately guess what the nearby pixels should look like and blend it all together properly.

Also, as Scott mentioned, it's raster - Illustrator is a vector editing software.

See [Why are raster images still used when vector images have so many advantages?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/44855/63979)

(Yes you can place raster images in Illustrator - but there isn't much functionality for rasters)

Comment: Thank you for this, I hadn't been able to find this tool by name, but will be sure to remember it for future use!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the "image" you are trying to sample is a **raster** image...

*No*, you can not sample a pattern from a raster image in Illustrator.

(Off hand, that doesn't even appear to be a "pattern", but rather pixel degradation due to raster image compression. So, it is most likely not consistent the way an actual "pattern" would be.)

Comment: Is there no way I can sample the images varying brightness values and then use them to fill an object with the same similar randomization that occurs due to the distortion in the original image?

Comment: As answered.. no. Not from a raster image in Illustrator.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do you know of a method to do so in Photoshop?

Comment: You can sample a region of a raster image and create a raster pattern in Photoshop. That is a different question though.

Comment: I ended up figuring that I could use adjustment layers in Photoshop to produce the results I needed, thank you for you help.