# Save an Image as SVG From Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, svg

Whilst I'm sure this has been answered before as it seems so simple, I'm asking again because I cannot get a straight answer anywhere.

All I want to do is save/export/change a .psd to a .svg.

I am using Photoshop CS6, NOT CC! I know you can Extract Assets in CC but you can't in CS6. I also DO NOT have access to Illustrator which seems to be the second most common answer.

Is there a way to achieve this or am I stuffed?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### You can't.

Photoshop is for saving raster images, not vector, while SVG is a vector format and you can't convert raster to vector (but you **can** do vice versa).

For more on this, see: [Why are raster images still used when vector images have so many advantages?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/44855/63979)

Comment: Thanks, I though that might be the answer

Comment: Although in theory, you can potentially save it as an svg, it won't actually **be** an svg, just the file type.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true. You can save SVG files from Photoshop.

You go to a vector layer, shape layer, text layer - basically any non-rasterized layer that you have in Photoshop and right click on that layer to choose 'Export As...' this will allow you to pick SVG from the drop down list in the top right.

Comment: I was trying to up vote your answer (but I am just a peasant lol - newbie for graphics design) because that is a correct answer and would be helpful for others. This was helpful to me when nothing else worked. Thanks!!